# How to calculate payload limit in GCM [python]

Tags: android, python-2.7, google-cloud-messaging, python-unicode

I am sending messages from google gcm using python. and GCM having [4kb(4096) limit](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#choose) in payload

```
s = "你好"
u = u"你好"
len(s) # output is 6
len(u) # output is 2 because of unicode
```

Now my question is how to count payload size.

or

what is google considering for size of payload as unicode or utf-8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the issue of google GCM
Confirmed form **gcm-dev-support**
Due to this i can send 12kb payload( even if limit was 4kb )

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#components-of-a-message) says:

> Data payload lets developers send up to 4KB of custom key/value pairs.

so you need to calculate **bytes** not **characters**. In your case your size is 6.